# ¿Como acceder a las propiedades o atributos de la clase padre en TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, poo

En lo referente a herencia en Typescript y usando este ejemplo simple:

```
class padre {
    public prop = "P-padre";
    constructor() {
    }
}

class hija extends padre {
    public prop = "P-hija"
    constructor(isSuper: boolean) {
        super();
        const muestra = (isSuper) ? super.prop : this.prop;

        console.log(muestra); //Output undefined
    }
}

let cliente = new hija(true);
```

¿como accedo al valor de `prop` de la clase padre? dentro de la clase hija.

Comment: Hasta deonde yo se no se puede, en el momento que creas un atributo con el mismo nombre el valor del hijo sobrecarga al atributo del padre.

Comment: Amigo gracias, Usted tiene toda la razón, no se puede acceder a la propiedad de la clase padre porque ya no existe, no hay tenido tiempo de revisar y corregir mis torpezas, gracias.